# Programmatically interpolating among multiple column values in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, interpolation

I have a table in my PostgreSQL db containing data of number of vehicles sold from 1995 to 2015 (with a gap of 5 years) like this:

```
ID.    veh_1995    veh_2000    veh_2005    veh_2010    veh_2015
1      200         425         526         725         623
2      400         478         1000        1500        2000
3      150         300         400         700         1100
4      700         800         1000        2000        5000
5      900         1500        1600        2000        2500
```

I would like to progammatically interpolate the values for the missing years and  for all IDs so that I have number of sold vehicles' records from 1995 to 2015. Could anyone suggest me how to do that? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885526/interpolation-between-two-values-in-a-single-query) shows interpolation between two values and [this link](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4145B6C4.1080605@zara.6.isreserved.com) show interpolation through `psql` approach. However, I am looking for the PostgreSQL Select query solution I don't want to go for the stored procedure or psql based approach. I am using PostgreSQL version 9.5 on Windows 7 based machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your interpolation is simple (you know beforehand where the interpolation points are located on the year dimension), the query is rather straightforward:

```
SELECT id,
       veh_1995,
       (veh_1995 + (veh_2000 - veh_1995) * 0.2)::int AS veh_1996,
       (veh_1995 + (veh_2000 - veh_1995) * 0.4)::int AS veh_1997,
       (veh_1995 + (veh_2000 - veh_1995) * 0.6)::int AS veh_1998,
       (veh_1995 + (veh_2000 - veh_1995) * 0.8)::int AS veh_1999,
       veh_2000,
       ... -- add similar lines to interpolate other years
       veh_2015
FROM my_table;
```