# How do I linearly interpolate a value in one table based on a different lookup table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, interpolation, linear-interpolation

CDC growth chart datasets provide a fine example of what I'm trying to accomplish: 
 http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/html_charts/statage.htm

Assume that their tables have been transposed into the following form:

cdc table with columns: chart_label, sex, age, tau, value

```
with tmp (chart_label, sex, age, tau, val) as (values 
('bmi for age','F',2,0.03,14.14735),
('bmi for age','F',2,0.05,14.39787),
('bmi for age','F',2,0.1,14.80134),
('bmi for age','F',2,0.25,15.52808),
('bmi for age','F',2,0.5,16.4234),
('bmi for age','F',2,0.75,17.42746),
('bmi for age','F',2,0.85,18.01821),
('bmi for age','F',2,0.9,18.44139),
('bmi for age','F',2,0.95,19.10624),
('bmi for age','F',2,0.97,19.56411),
('bmi for age','F',2.041667,0.03,14.13226),
('bmi for age','F',2.041667,0.05,14.38019),
('bmi for age','F',2.041667,0.1,14.77965),
('bmi for age','F',2.041667,0.25,15.49976),
('bmi for age','F',2.041667,0.5,16.38804),
('bmi for age','F',2.041667,0.75,17.38582),
('bmi for age','F',2.041667,0.85,17.97371),
('bmi for age','F',2.041667,0.9,18.39526),
('bmi for age','F',2.041667,0.95,19.05824),
('bmi for age','F',2.041667,0.97,19.51534))
select * from tmp;
```

I want to write a PostgreSQL function to return the estimated tau for a given chart, sex, age, and value using linear interpolation to estimate the tau if there is no exact value available for the inputs.

For example (pseudo code):

```
select interp('bmi for age', 'F', 2.02, 15);
```

Should return a tau value between .1 and .25 (roughly 0.141) since it will be interpolating between these two rows:

```
('bmi for age','F',2,0.1,14.80134),
('bmi for age','F',2,0.25,15.52808),
```

I do realize that linear interpolation may not be the ideal solution for finding the appropriate percentile, but as I said, the CDC growth charts are an appropriate approximation to my actual use case.

The only thing I had to go on was [this post](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4145B6C4.1080605@zara.6.isreserved.com), and these other similar questions on SO [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885526/interpolation-between-two-values-in-a-single-query) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154678/programmatically-interpolating-among-multiple-column-values-in-postgresql?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a few solutions based on various searches on SO, links in the question, and documentation. The unfortunate thing about each of these solutions is that they are relatively slow because the lookup gets called once per value.

Also, each could likely be improved with error handling, input validation, and better logic in dealing with boundary conditions.  For now, I just return the low/high extreme values if the value requested is beyond the scale of the table.

**SQL Solution:**

```
create or replace function cdcInterp(_valtype text, 
                                     _insex character(1), 
                                     _inage numeric, 
                                     _inval numeric)
-- _valtype should be one of either 'bmi for age', 'wt for age', or 'ht for age'
-- _insex should be one of either 'M' or 'F' 
returns numeric as 
  $$
-- make a lookup table
with lkup as (
  select * 
  from cdc_chart_value 
  where chart_label = _valtype
    and sex = _insex
  order by abs(age - _inage) asc, age, tau 
  -- order by ensures that I am using the closest age, 
  -- with ties defaulting to the younger age
  -- 10 is a magic number: it is the number of taus for each age 
  -- (0.03, 0.05, 0.10, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.85, 0.90, 0.95, 0.97)
  limit 10
  ),
-- find high and low values needed to do interpolation
  vals as (select 
            -- x1 is the lower value
            (SELECT lkup.val FROM lkup WHERE lkup.val <= _inval ORDER BY lkup.val DESC LIMIT 1) as x1,
            -- x2 is the upper value
            (SELECT lkup.val FROM lkup WHERE lkup.val >= _inval ORDER BY lkup.val ASC  LIMIT 1) as x2,
            -- y1 is the lower tau
            (SELECT lkup.tau FROM lkup WHERE lkup.val <= _inval ORDER BY lkup.val DESC LIMIT 1) as y1,
            -- y2 is the upper tau
            (SELECT lkup.tau FROM lkup WHERE lkup.val >= _inval ORDER BY lkup.val ASC  LIMIT 1) as y2
          from lkup)

-- interpolate, or not, as needed
SELECT
   CASE
     WHEN vals.x1 = vals.x2 THEN vals.y1 -- if equal, then return the exact tau
     when vals.x1 is null then vals.y2 -- if the lower value is null, then return the lowest tau (.03)
     when vals.x2 is null then vals.y1 -- if the upper value is null, then returr the highest tau (.97)
     ELSE                (vals.y1 + (_inval-vals.x1)/(vals.x2-vals.x1)*(vals.y2-vals.y1)) -- otherwise interpolate linearly
   END AS y
FROM vals
$$
language sql stable;
```

This is a bit slower than I was hoping (33 msec per query).  Wondering if there is a way to do this faster?

**PLPGSQL solution:**  (takes about 50% longer than the SQL solution)

```
create or replace function interp2(_valtype text, 
                                   _insex character(1), 
                                   _inage numeric, 
                                   _inval numeric)
returns numeric as 
$$
DECLARE
  x1 numeric;
  x2 numeric;
  y1 numeric;
  y2 numeric;
  y numeric;
begin
  -- the overhead of creating/dropping a temporary table is bad
  drop table if exists _tmp_lkup;
  create temp table _tmp_lkup   as 
    (select * 
      from cdc_chart_value 
      where chart_label = _valtype
        and sex = _insex
      order by abs(age - _inage) asc, age, tau 
      -- order by ensures that I am using the closest age, 
      -- with ties defaulting to the younger age
      -- 10 is a magic number: it is the number of taus for each age 
      -- (0.03, 0.05, 0.10, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.85, 0.90, 0.95, 0.97)
      limit 10
    );
  x1 := (SELECT _tmp_lkup.val FROM _tmp_lkup WHERE _tmp_lkup.val <= _inval ORDER BY _tmp_lkup.val DESC LIMIT 1);
  x2 := (SELECT _tmp_lkup.val FROM _tmp_lkup WHERE _tmp_lkup.val >= _inval ORDER BY _tmp_lkup.val ASC  LIMIT 1);
  y1 := (SELECT _tmp_lkup.tau FROM _tmp_lkup WHERE _tmp_lkup.val <= _inval ORDER BY _tmp_lkup.val DESC LIMIT 1);
  y2 := (SELECT _tmp_lkup.tau FROM _tmp_lkup WHERE _tmp_lkup.val >= _inval ORDER BY _tmp_lkup.val ASC  LIMIT 1);

  -- interpolate, or not, as needed
  y := (select CASE
         WHEN x1 = x2 THEN y1 -- if equal, then return the exact tau
         when x1 is null then y2 -- if the lower value is null, then return the lowest tau (.05)
         when x2 is null then y1 -- if the upper value is null, then retunr the highest tau (.95)
         ELSE                (y1 + (_inval-x1)/(x2-x1)*(y2-y1)) -- otherwise interpolate linearly
       END);
  return y; 
end;
$$ language plpgsql volatile;
```

I believe that a faster solution would be to reduce the number of times that the lookup is created. e.g., by using a plpgsql loop over sex and interpolating all of the male points, then all of the female points, and returning the union of both sets of results?

Another possible solution might be to use the `griddata` interpolation found in the python/scipy extension.